# deseo obtener solo dos campos de mi tabla usando Métodos de consulta derivados

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo una tabla de bd de mas de varios campos y quiero hacer un query de Métodos de consulta derivados que me ofrece java spring boot, que solo me muestre los campos email y nombre a partir del nombre de usuario algo a si como un select, se que si quiero obtener todos los campos de la tabla a partir del nombre de usuario es a si "findByNombreUsuario"  esto es lo que he estado intentando hacer " SelectEmailAndNombreFindByNombreUsuario" pero no funciona. Aquí el código.

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Integer> {

    //obtener un usuario apartir del nombre de usuario
    Optional<Usuario> findByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario);
    //obtener el id de un campo
    Optional<Usuario> SelectIdAndEmailAndNombreFindByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario);
    //boolean para comprobar si existe o no exite por nombre
    boolean existsByNombreUsuario(String nombreUsuario);
    //comprobar si existe el email
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: No encuentro el link de la documentation que tenia guardado, pero estoy seguro que  `Select ` + `nombre de los campos` no es parte de las funciones de Spring Data para la creación de queries.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si desde los métodos de consulta se puedan especificar los campos de salida de la consulta. De lo que estoy seguro es que se pueden especificar los criterios de búsqueda (buscar por nombre de usuario, email, etc.) y que las consultas por métodos de consulta por lo general retornan objetos.

En su caso, para intentar hacer "SelectEmailAndNombreFindByNombreUsuario" yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
@Query("select u.Email, u.Nombre from Usuario u where u.NombreUsuario = :nombreUsuario")
List<Object> selectEmailAndNombreFindByNombreUsuario(@Param("nombreUsuario") String nombreUsuario);
```

También puede crear una clase con sólo dos atributos "email" y "nombre" llamada UsuarioMinDto, de esa forma podría cambiar el tipo de retorno del método selectEmailAndNombreFindByNombreUsuario de List a UsuarioMinDto.

Nota: Todo esto asumiendo que el nombre de usuario es único en la base de datos.

Comment: Para más y mejor información, este es el sitio oficial sobre los métodos de consulta:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods